# Xdebug Profiler Aggregate always crashes (xdebug.profiler_aggregate=1 causes coredump in xdebug.so xdebug_profiler_output_aggr_data())

Tags: php-fpm, segmentation-fault, xdebug

Whenever I go to localhost I get a 404 error, until I mark xdebug.profiler_aggregate=0
The reason why is xdebug.so coredumps (SEGFAULT)

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_aggregate=1
```

`$ dmesg`

```
[  584.455746] php-fpm7.1[4645]: segfault at 30 ip 00007f5d3969f6b3 sp 00007ffdc8b87a20 error 4 in xdebug.so[7f5d3967e000+39000]
```

`$ sudo cat /var/log/php7.1-fpm.log`

```
[31-Aug-2017 14:59:01] WARNING: [pool www] child 4645 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 0.138218 seconds from start
[31-Aug-2017 14:59:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 4647 started
[31-Aug-2017 14:59:07] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[31-Aug-2017 14:59:07] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
in xdebug_profiler_output_aggr_data() with 0 entries
```

When I change the last line in the conf file to
`xdebug.profiler_aggregate=0`
it works fine again.

I've tried reinstalling php, xdebug, and updating and restarting, and I've tried removing all other xdebug settings except for that one

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you have installed Xdebug, but I suggest you to install a recent version of Xdebug, with pecl, not with apt (if you have apt).

```
sudo apt-get remove php-xdebug
sudo apt install php-pear php-dev
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Comment: I used apt, most likely with the famous ~ondrej PPA

Comment: You can use apt for installing php and pecl for installing xdebug